# Where to specify the phone number when using Intent.ACTION_SENDTO?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-intent

In [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html#Messaging), the following example is given:

```
public void composeMmsMessage(String message, Uri attachment) {
  Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
  intent.setType(HTTP.PLAIN_TEXT_TYPE);
  intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
  intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, attachment);
  if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
      startActivity(intent);
  }
}
```

Where is the destination number specified?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:xxxxxxxxxx");
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't. That's a bug in that code. `ACTION_SENDTO` takes an `smsto:` or `mailto:` `Uri`:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse("smsto:123456"));
```

where 123456 is the desired phone number.